# Save Image in a folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image

I am trying save a image to folder with this function:

```
<WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function SaveCapturedImage(ByVal data As String, httpContext As HttpContext) As Boolean
        Dim fileName As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy hh-mm-ss")

        'Convert Base64 Encoded string to Byte Array.
        Dim imageBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(data.Split(",")(1))

        'Save the Byte Array as Image File.
        Dim filePath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/Captures/{0}.jpg", fileName))
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, imageBytes)
        Return True
    End Function
```

But i have the following error:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'File' accepts this number of arguments

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: try System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes

Comment: If you set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set is as the default for new projects), it might point out some problems with the code for you, and even suggest corrections.

Answer (score 0):

well, it seems strange that you doing a comma delimited split, and assuming the data comes after the first ",". Are you sure that is correct?

But remember, since the web method is static - does not have use of viewstate, nor controls, nor the default referances (improts) setup on that web page?

Then you need to qualify the reference

eg this:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function SaveCapturedImage(ByVal data As String, httpContext As HttpContext) As Boolean
    Dim fileName As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy hh-mm-ss")

    'Convert Base64 Encoded string to Byte Array.
    Dim imageBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(data.Split(",")(1))

    'Save the Byte Array as Image File.
    Dim filePath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/Captures/{0}.jpg", fileName))
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, imageBytes)
    Return True
End Function
```